# GAM: Confidence interval for the covariates in gratia (R)

Tags: r, confidence-interval, generalized-additive-model

I am using gratia to fit a gam model such as:

```
formula = as.formula(paste(Region, "~ s(date, k=20) + ID"))
```

you can extract the CI of Region using:

```
ciGP2 <- confint(mod, parm = "s(date)",  type = "confidence")

mod <- gam(formula, data = dat, method = "REML")
```

I was wondering:

1. I would like to know the confidence interval for the covariate "Region"
2. Maybe it is the solution to 1 =); how do I get fitted "date" value for a specific "Region" value? (that would probably allow me to calculate the CI of "date" based on the CI of "Region"?)
3. Finally, the estimated values of the GAM are different from the original. Is there a way to obtain the estimated values in their original metric?

Thank you very much

[image]

Comment: What does your `gam()` call look like? 3. is likely due to either i) using a non-Gaussian distribution for `family` or ii) not appreciating that smooths are (mostly) subject to identifiability constraints (in this case a sum-to-zero constraint) which means the smooths are centred about the model constant term `(Intercept)`.

Comment: Hello, I just added two of the gam. What are you thoughts about? how can I have the actual values rather than an estimation centered on 0? thank you again!

Comment: I also added the gam call: mod <- gam(formula, data = dat, method = "REML")

Comment: also, mod <- gam(formula, data = dat) does'nt change the estimated values

Answer (score 0):

### Q1

By the convention with `confint()` (the generic in base R), the coverage of the interval is given by argument `level`, which is typically set to `0.95` such that the interval is a 95% confidence interval. Check out `?confint.gam` for more detail.

### Q2

You have this back to front; you don't get a fitted value for `date`, you get one for `Region` that is a function of `date` and `ID`. If you want to know what value of Region were estimated for input `date` values then look at the `est` column in the outputm with the `date` column indicating what values of `date` the estimate and interval are for:

```r
library("mgcv")
library("gratia")
dat <- gamSim(1, n = 500, dist = "normal", scale = 2)
mod <- gam(y ~ s(x0) + s(x1) + s(x2) + s(x3), data = dat, method = "REML")

## point-wise interval
ci <- confint(mod, parm = "s(x1)", type = "confidence")
ci
```

which gives

```
#> # A tibble: 200 x 8
#>    smooth by_variable      x1   est    se  crit lower upper
#>    <chr>  <fct>         <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
#>  1 s(x1)  NA          0.00251 -2.04 0.296  1.96 -2.62 -1.46
#>  2 s(x1)  NA          0.00752 -2.04 0.287  1.96 -2.60 -1.47
#>  3 s(x1)  NA          0.0125  -2.03 0.279  1.96 -2.58 -1.49
#>  4 s(x1)  NA          0.0175  -2.03 0.270  1.96 -2.56 -1.50
#>  5 s(x1)  NA          0.0225  -2.02 0.262  1.96 -2.54 -1.51
#>  6 s(x1)  NA          0.0276  -2.02 0.254  1.96 -2.52 -1.52
#>  7 s(x1)  NA          0.0326  -2.01 0.246  1.96 -2.50 -1.53
#>  8 s(x1)  NA          0.0376  -2.01 0.239  1.96 -2.48 -1.54
#>  9 s(x1)  NA          0.0426  -2.01 0.232  1.96 -2.46 -1.55
#> 10 s(x1)  NA          0.0476  -2.00 0.226  1.96 -2.44 -1.56
#> # ... with 190 more rows
```

If you want to get point estimates and intervals for the observed data, pass the original data to the `newdata` argument of `confint.gam`

## Q3

This is likely due to either

1. your using a non-Gaussian distribution for family, or
2. not appreciating that smooths are (mostly) subject to identifiability constraints (in this case a sum-to-zero constraint) which means the smooths are centred about the model constant term (Intercept)

Note that the `est` in the output is the estimated **partial** effect on the response of the smooth of `date` for specified values of `date`. It isn't an estimated value in the sense that it is scaled as per the original response.

Comment: thank you for answering my question so quickly! for question 1: I guess, this is the same problem as question 2: "you don't get a fitted value for date, you get one for Region that is a function of date and ID". So that is why I can't get any confidence interval too for date? which actually make sense...